# Multiple inheritance and parent constructor called mutiple times

Tags: javascript, object, inheritance, constructor, traits

Say I have the following "class tree" :

```
              Element
               /   \
              /     \
             /       \
  Positionnable     Sizeable
             \        /
              \      /
               \    /
             Rectangle
```

Now say the element constructor does something :

```
var Element = function() {
    this.traits = [ ];
};
```

And say the sub classes constructors require their parent constructor (Element constructor) to be called before doing their own work :

```
var Positionnable = function() {
    Element.call( this );
    this.traits.position = { x : 0, y : 0 }; // Requires this.traits to be set.
};

var Sizable = function() {
    Element.call( this );
    this.traits.size = { w : 0, h : 0 }; // Requires this.traits to be set.
};
```

The problem is, when I make Rectangle inherit from Positionnable and Sizable (by merging prototypes), the constructor from Element will be called twice, which can be a problem depending on what is does :

```
var Rectangle = function() {
    Positionnable.call( this ); // Calls Element constructor
    Sizeable.call( this );      // Calls Element constructor
};
```

So I thought about two possibilities: adding booleans somewhere that would be set to true when a constructor has been called to avoid doing it more than once, but that looks dirty.

Or i could call ALL the direct or indirect parent constructors in Rectangle :

```
var Positionnable = function() {
    this.traits.position = { x : 0, y : 0 }; // Assumes parent constructor has been called
};

var Sizable = function() {
    this.traits.size = { w : 0, h : 0 }; // Assumes parent constructor has been called
};

var Rectangle = function() {
    Element.call( this );
    Positionnable.call( this ); // Does no longer call Element constructor
    Sizeable.call( this );      // Does no longer call Element constructor
};
```

But that would assume that Element constructor is called before Positionnable and Sizable constructors (meaning that those two would fail when called separatly), that would also involve (for the coder) to recursivly look for all direct or indirect parent classes to call their constructors (might be annoying if the inheritance tree is more complicated than this), and I would have the same problem as I have now if I need to create a sub class for Rectangle.

So how could I have constructors called only a single time?

Comment: Or maybe i could try to use compositing...

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traditionally in JavaScript it's best to avoid [multiple inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance) altogether and use [mixins](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2011/05/31/a-fresh-look-at-javascript-mixins/) when necessary to share functionality. Multiple inheritance leads to all sorts of problem including the infamous [dreaded diamond of doom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) problem (which is the problem you're facing).

Different languages use different methods to resolve the diamond problem. For example Java makes use of [interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interface_%28computing%29) instead of multiple inheritance, C++ employs [virtual inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance) to resolve ambiguities and languages like Python and Dylan employ a [method resolution order](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/) to linearize a [heterarchy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heterarchy).

Nonetheless all of the aforementioned techniques are insufficiently powerful to solve the diamond constructor problem you are facing. Interfaces are useless in dynamic languages like JavaScript: duck typing plays a more significant role. Virtual inheritance unnecessarily complicates matters. Linearization resolves the order of inherited methods but doesn't address your problem.

There are two techniques you may employ to resolve this problem in JavaScript:

1. Abandon multiple inheritance altogether and use mixins to share functionality like most JavaScript programmers do.
2. Conditionally call the base class constructor from the derived class constructor depending upon whether `this` is an instance of the derived class constructor.

I would recommend that you use mixins. However the end decision is yours to make. On my behalf I'll simply present the advantages and disadvantages of each technique.

## Mixins

Mixins are the traditional way of implementing multiple inheritance in JavaScript, and most of the time traditional methods are proven to be the best. A mixin is like a Java interface **with** the implementation. You could (and should in my humble opinion) refactor your code as follows:

```
function Element() {
    // constructor logic
}

function positionable(that, x, y) {
    that.x = x;
    that.y = y;
}

function sizable(that, w, h) {
    that.w = w;
    that.h = h;
}

function Rectangle(x, y, w, h) {
    Element.call(this);
    positionable(this, x, y);
    sizable(this, w, h);
}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Element.prototype);
```

As you can see in the above code `positionable` and `sizable` are not constructors. They are mixins - you're not supposed to use them to create instances. You use them to *augment* instances.

In JavaScript it's a best practice to create classes which inherit from a single base class and to use mixins to share additional functionality as required.

**Bonus:** Programming is a lot like English. Nouns are like classes, verbs are like methods and adjectives are like mixins. Words ending in *"able"* are usually adjectives. Hence `positionable` and `sizable` should be implemented as mixins.

## Classes

If you're still hell bent on implementing `Positionable` and `Sizable` as classes then I'm afraid there's not much I can do to change your mind. Hence I'll show you how to solve your problem using classes and demonstrate why this technique is inferior to using mixins:

```
function Element() {
    this.traits = [];
}

function Position() {
    if (this instanceof Position) Element.call(this);
    this.traits.position = { x: 0, y: 0 };
}

Position.prototype = Object.create(Element.prototype);


function Sizable() {
    if (this instanceof Sizable) Element.call(this);
    this.traits.size = { w: 0, h: 0 };
}

Sizable.prototype = Object.create(Element.prototype);

function Rectangle() {
    Element.call(this);
    Positionable.call(this);
    Sizable.call(this);
}

Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Element.prototype);
_.extend(Rectangle.prototype, Positionable.prototype, Sizable.prototype);
```

As you can see this code is definitely uglier than the code written using mixins. Inside the `Positionable` and `Sizable` constructors we check whether `this` is an instance of the respective constructors before calling the `Element` constructor, solving the diamond constructor problem.

We use the Underscore.js [`extend`](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) function to copy the properties of `Positionable.prototype` and `Sizable.prototype` onto `Rectangle.prototype`. I'll leave it to you to figure out why this is not the recommended method to implement multiple inheritance.

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer, i will read it after work :)

Comment: Okay i'll see if i can do something element using mixins.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, first one is better than the second approach.

However, it is generally not a good idea to have multiple inheritance.

It is going to complicate your code over time.

If we think in Java for a second, it makes more sense to

```
Rectangle extends Element implements Positionable, Sizable
```

I think you should rethink about class hierarchy of your code.

**EDIT:**

If you are doing this, then here's how I would go about.
It is not tested. You should try and play with it, and add more functionalities.

```
function extend(subClass, superClass) {
    var superclasses = subClass._superclasses || (subClass._superclasses = []);
    addSuperClasses(superclasses, superClass._superclasses);
    superclasses.push(superClass);
    subClass.prototype.initialize = initialize;
}

function addSuperClasses(superclasses, list) {
    if (list) {
        for (var i = 0, l = list.length, superclass; i < l; i++) {
            superclass = list[i];
            if (superclasses.indexOf(superclass) === -1) {
                superclasses.push(superclass);
            }
        }
    }
}

function initialize() {
    if (!this._initialized) {
        this._initialized = true;
        var superclasses = this.constructor._superclasses;
        if (superclasses) {
            for (var i = 0, l = superclasses.length; i < l; i++) {
                superclasses[i].call(this);
            }
        }
    }
}

function Element() {}

function Positionable() {
    this.initialize();
    this.traits.position = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    };
}
extend(Positionable, Element);

function Sizable() {
    this.initialize();
    this.traits.size = {
        w: 0,
        h: 0
    };
}
extend(Sizable, Element);

function Rectangle() {}
extend(Rectangle, Positionable);
extend(Rectangle, Sizable);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Positionable and Sizable are not just interfaces actually, i need them them to bring their own properties.

Comment: In your approach, it seems to me that there will be some element class that is going to be positionable, but not sizable, and vice versa. If all element classes will be positionable and sizable, why divide them into two separate classes?

Comment: " there will be some element class that is going to be positionable, but not sizable, and vice versa ". That's correct. A disc for example will have a radius and will only inherit from Positionnable. `var Disc = function() { Positionnable.call( this ); this.traits.radius = 0; };` This is why i can't make, for example, Positionnable extend Sizeable or vice versa.

Comment: Thanks, i'll also have a look to this.